# JSON - Get value of row's next column value

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the JSON structure of rows I get exported from a Google Sheets:

```
[
    {
        "COLUMN1HEADER": "V1",
        "COLUMN2HEADER": "response 1"
    },
    {
        "COLUMN1HEADER": "V2",
        "COLUMN2HEADER": "response 2"
    },
    {
        "COLUMN1HEADER": "V3",
        "COLUMN2HEADER": "response 3"
    }
]
```

The user input is equal to a COLUMN1HEADER value (for example, `let input = 'V2'`) and from this string value I'm struggling to get the COLUMN2HEADER value ("response 2") as return.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question.  The user enters a value for COLUMN1HEADER and you want to return the matching COLUMN2HEADER value?

Comment: Yes, the user enters V1 (for example) and the function (after parsing the JSON code) has to return "response 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()`, like this:

```
function test() {
  const searchValue = 'V2';
  const jsonData = `[
    {
      "COLUMN1HEADER": "V1",
      "COLUMN2HEADER": "response 1"
    },
    {
      "COLUMN1HEADER": "V2",
      "COLUMN2HEADER": "response 2"
    },
    {
      "COLUMN1HEADER": "V3",
      "COLUMN2HEADER": "response 3"
    }
  ]`;
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  const result = getFieldValue_({ data: data, searchKey: 'COLUMN1HEADER', searchValue: searchValue, resultKey: 'COLUMN2HEADER' });
  console.log(result);
}


function getFieldValue_({ data, searchKey, searchValue, resultKey } = {}) {
  const matches = data.filter(obj => obj[searchKey] === searchValue);
  if (!matches.length) {
    return null;
  }
  const firstMatch = matches[0];
  return firstMatch[resultKey];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could created the JSON like this:

```
function getData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify( {"values":vs}));
}

{values:[["COLUMN1HEADER","COLUMN2HEADER"],["V1","response 1"],["V2","response 2"],["V3","response 3"]]}
```

Then you would have an output similar to what Sheets API provides and you would be able to use setValues() to drop it right back into a spreadsheet.